# Is the polynomial $x^{p^n} + 1$ irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$ when $ p$ is prime and odd?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

> Polynomial $x^{p^n} + 1$, $p$ is prime and odd,  is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$

I can't use Eisenstein's criterion because $1|a_n$ , $a_n=1$.

Since $p$ is odd,  $p^n$ is odd too, so $-1$ is zero of $x^{p^n} + 1$
Hence, $$x^{p^n} + 1  = (x+1) ( x^{p^{n-1}}  -  x^{p^{n-2}}  +  x^{p^{n-3}} + \dots + x^{p}  +1)$$ 
I don't know how use the fact about $p$ being prime.

Comment: Can you find any zeros?

Comment: Of course not!!

Comment: Hint: What is $(-1)^s$ for odd $s$?

Comment: yes, i have progress with this hint , because -1 is zero if p is odd ,  how use the fact abou p is prime?

Comment: The fact that $p$ is prime is hardly necessary, so you don't need to use it at all. The polynomial $x^n+1$ is always divisible by $x+1$ when $n$ is odd.

Answer (score 1):

You've shown that $x+1$ is a factor of $x^{p^n}+1$; thus, $x^{p^n}+1$ is reducible.

Comment: yes, but i dont understand why p need be prime if x+1|$x^{p^n}$+1 when p is odd and p dont need be necessarily prime.

Comment: @andre: You don't. The only thing you need is that $p$ is odd and greater than $1$ (and $n\gt0$).